# acts-as-taggable-on gem -- "taggings_count" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

After upgrading the gem `acts-as-taggable-on` and applying the migrations:

```
   rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
   rake db:migrate
```

I keep having the errors in my **tests**:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist                                                      
       LINE 1: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_coun...
```

Comment: Taggings_count should be under the tags table...Make sure your migrations went through.

Comment: rake db:test:prepare